# How to print from the first period to the second period using awk?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

`20200601.title.info.event.txt` is the file name.  I want to use awk to print whatever is in between the first two periods.  So in this case "title."  Appreciate any help.

The file is a $1 variable.  All files are formatted with the same info.

I'm using

FILE=$1

DATE=`echo $FILE | awk '{printf "%", substr ($1,1,8)' -`

TITLE=

Need to grab the TITLE in between the the first two periods to use as a variable elsewhere. The TITLE will be different for every file. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: `awk -F. '{print $2}' <<<"$filename"`

Comment: `echo 20200601.title.info.event.txt | cut -d. -f2`   or  `echo 20200601.title.info.event.txt | { IFS=. read -r _ var _ ; echo "$var" ;  }`

Comment: Why do you want to use awk to print part of a file name? Do you have an existing awk script and you want to print part of the FILENAME variable along with other output or what? Please [edit] your question to provide more context and also show what you've tried yourself so far so we can best help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
cut -d'.' -f2 <<< 20200601.title.info.event.txt
```

This is the straightforward way to *cut* a string.

And with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) like @Mihir wrote in comments:

```
awk -F. '{print $2}' <<< 20200601.title.info.event.txt
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Thank you! Even answered my follow up about how to print everything, but the extension. awk - F.txt '{print $1}'. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Using awk's `split()` instead of `FS` in case it's used for something else::

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    split("20200601.title.info.event.txt",a,".")
    print a[1]
}'
title
```

Using bash's `=~` operator:

```
$ [[ "20200601.title.info.event.txt" =~ \.[^.]*\. ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[0]:1:-1}
title
```

Using sed:

```
$ sed 's/^[^.]*.\|\..*//g' <<< "20200601.title.info.event.txt"
title
```

In all cases you could set the string to a variable first and use the variable instead of the string.